# MS Access VBA Function for Query WHERE IN statement?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function to turn a result from a simple query into string so i can use it in an IN statement in another query:

Function:

```
Public Function TransposeColumn_INCriteria(TableName As String, ColumnName As String) As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sResult As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim dtDateTime_Now As Date

dtDateTime_Now = Now()
sSQL = "SELECT [" & ColumnName & "] FROM [" & TableName & "] WHERE ((([" & TableName & "].[DateTime_From])<=#" & dtDateTime_Now & "#) AND (Nz([" & TableName & "].[DateTime_To],#" & dtDateTime_Now & "#)>=#" & dtDateTime_Now & "#))"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF
    sResult = sResult & ",'" & rs.Fields(0).Value & "'"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

TransposeColumn_INCriteria = Mid(sResult, 2)
End Function
```

running the function returns the following:
'1111','2222','3333'

Copy and pasting the result into the following works and returns 40000 records:

```
SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column3 IN ('1111','2222','3333')
```

But calling the function instead returns no records:

```
SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column3 IN (TransposeColumn_INCriteria("table4","column1"))
```

I had assumed this is because the results are being treated as a single string of "'1111','2222','3333'", but;

Modifying the function to return '1111' fails as well.

Modifying the function to return 1111 works correctly.

**The field is a string data type.**

I can't just join to table4 as **table1 is in a linked oracle database**, and **table4 is a local access table**, and with a join the query takes 40 minutes to run. With the values in the IN() statement, it takes approximately 2 minutes to run.

Is there a way to do this? Am I missing something obvious?

*Edit: I didn't specify the field data type*

*Another Edit:* I did consider the following, but after 1hr 20mins I killed the process, so for whatever reason I assume its significantly less efficient when called in Access:

```
SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column3 IN (SELECT column1 FROM table4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the content of an `IN (...)` clause cannot be evaluated at runtime, it must be static. Possible workarounds: 1. Write the keys into a temp table in Oracle and join there, with an additional user key for multi-user scenarios if necessary. -- 2. Build/modify the whole query SQL at runtime.

Comment: Is ``table1.column3`` string type or numeric? If numeric, that's how it should be - ``return 1111 works correctly``.

Comment: @Andre: Unfortunately I cannot change anything on the Oracle side at all. I was hoping to have a Query that I can save as I will be executing it as part of a long and convoluted process that I have very limited control over. Its interesting that it works if the function only returns 1111 though if the IN statement cannot be evaluated at runtime?

Comment: Try ``WHERE table1.column3 IN (" & TransposeColumn_INCriteria("table4","column1") & ")" ``

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. 
SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column3 IN (" & TransposeColumn_INCriteria("table4","column1") & ")" 
is not a value SQL Statement. Was the intention to add additional quotes before and after the function call?

Comment: Just a quick pointer - you don't need the table name appended to the field name if the field name only appears in a single table.  All your fields come from table1 so `SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM table1 WHERE column3 IN ('1111','2222','3333')` would work (apart from the problem in the question).

Comment: Yeah I know, but it also doesn't effect the functionality, and while I'm using only 1 table to test the function call, the real world query will have about 5 tables all joined on the oracle side.

Comment: I guess:  sSQL = "SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2 FROM table1
WHERE table1.column3 IN (" & TransposeColumn_INCriteria("table4","column1") & ")"  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

Comment: ah yes I assume that would work from VBA, but I'm trying to call the function from an access query object, not VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution via VBA seems simple and affordable.
I think, for Access constructor possible only explcitly described in IN (val1,val2 ...) expressions. So, string "1,2,3" - is 1 value eq condition table1.column3 in("1,2,3").

If there is no option other than to work through a query, you can build such a construction:
1.Function for prepare and sent parameters to access query object (like TransposeColumn_INCriteria)

```
Dim QueryParamArray() As String

Public Function GetParam(n As Long, Optional TableName As String = "", Optional ColumnName As String) As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, sResult As String, sSQL As String
Dim dtDateTime_Now As Date
    If Len(TableName) > 0 Then
        dtDateTime_Now = Now()
        sSQL =sSQL = "SELECT [" & ColumnName & "] FROM [" & TableName & "] WHERE ((([" & TableName & "].[DateTime_From])<=#" & dtDateTime_Now & "#) AND (Nz([" & TableName & "].[DateTime_To],#" & dtDateTime_Now & "#)>=#" & dtDateTime_Now & "#))"
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            rs.MoveLast
            ReDim QueryParamArray(rs.RecordCount)
            rs.MoveFirst
        End If
        Dim idx As Long
        idx = LBound(QueryParamArray)
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            QueryParamArray(idx) = rs.Fields(0).Value
            rs.MoveNext
            idx = idx + 1
        Loop
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
    End If
    If n <= UBound(QueryParamArray) and n >= LBound(QueryParamArray) Then
        GetParam = QueryParamArray(n)
    Else
        Debug.Print "GetParam:", n, TableName, ColumnName, "Param number out of range. (This is not error)"
        GetParam = ""
    End If
End Function
```

2.In Access query constructor create WHERE clause like this

```
SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2
FROM table1
WHERE (((table1.column3) In (GetParam(0,"Table4","ObjName") 
          ,GetParam(1),GetParam(2),GetParam(3),GetParam(4)
          ,GetParam(5),GetParam(6),GetParam(7)  )
      ));
```

If there are too many parameters, it is better to do it by modifying the WHERE clause conditions in the access query (dynamic SQL)

```
   set qdf=QueryDefs("MyQuery")
   sSQL=qdf.sql
   ' manipulation with WHERE clause
```

Comment: I did originally look to returning an array or strings, but I couldn't think how to transpose the output with a singular statement. While it causes me physical pain to put lots of unused GetParam(n) calls in the WHERE IN() as the number of entries will vary over time, I don't see I have much choice, so will likely use this approach if I can't find another way to do it (although I'll likely use a class instead of a function to avoid the global array variable). Thanks.

Comment: I agree with ``causes me physical pain``;) I think, lots of unused calls not is problem, problem if insufficient number of calls.